# Confusion about error of program in C

Tags: c, puts

When I compile this code I get an error "**in front of int val, there isn't**" ; 
how can I get rid of this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char card_name[3];
    puts("카드 이름을 입력하세요: ");
    int val = 0;
    if(card_name[0]=='K') {
        val = 10;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
        val = 10;
    } 
    else if (card_name[0] == 'J') { 
        val = 10; 
    } 
    else if (card_name[0] == 'A') {
        val = 11;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        val = atoi(card_name); 
    }

    printf("카드값은 다음과 같습니다 : %i/n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next time onwards,posting the **exact** error message like `syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'` will be really helpful to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare all variables in the top of `main` just after `{` ,i.e, declare `val` before the first `puts`. It is because your compiler uses C89 which forbids mixed declarations and code. From C99 onwards , they can be declared (almost) anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, C89 does not support declaring variables other than at the start of the block.  If you are using clang or gcc, you might want to add '-std=gnu99' to your CFLAGS.  If using another compiler or an IDE, look for the language and change it to C99 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the compiler requires that all definitions of varaibles would be in the beginninh of block.
Try to write

```
char card_name[3];
int val = 0;
puts("카드 이름을 입력하세요: ");
```

Also take into account that array card_name is not initialized.